# Как засечь время нажатия клавиши в bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Подскажите, как можно засечь время нажатия клавиши штатными средствами Linux (Пишу скрипт на Bash)?
Чтобы понять суть задания: разрабатывается клавиатурный почерк, т.е. засекается время нажатия клавиши, частоту ошибок и тд и тп. 
Использовать можно только BASH, С отпадает

Comment: Рекомендую почитать про команды `read` и `time`. Если нет ман-страницы, попробуйте `help` из баша. Консоль можно перевести в raw-режим, для получения сырых кодов. Уже не помню как, к сожалению.

Comment: @kisssko, разве time не засекает время обычной команды? ведь необходимо также знать сколько времени клавиша была в положении down и когда она стала up

Comment: @vp_arth это консольная оболочка и интерпретатор, а никак не терминал.

Comment: @Илья да, `time` будет измерять время ожидания команды `read`. Если нужны "отпускания" - то придётся в raw-режиме работать.

Comment: @kisssko, правильно ли я понимаю, что для "отпускания" использовать raw режим СОВМЕСТНО  с time?

Comment: тут уже как фантазия подскажет. Я лишь предлагаю средства. Кстати, по поводу raw-mode можете посмотреть [man kbd_mode](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=kbd_mode&russian=2&category=&submit=%F0%CF%CB%C1%DA%C1%D4%D8+man).

Comment: @kisssko, вряд ли `time` годится для таких замеров. Наверное можно попробовать `date +%s.%N`, выводящую секунды и наносекунды после точки (от Epoch)

Answer (score 1):

`xev` в иксах и `showkey` в голой консоли пишут в лог события клавиатуры. Оттуда можно получить время нажатия клавиш.

Есть в каждом линуксе. xev :

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x169, subw 0x0, time 31281490, (165,-10), root:(265,118),
    state 0x2000, keycode 39 (keysym 0x6d9, Cyrillic_yeru), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d1 8b) "ы"
    XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d1 8b) "ы"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x169, subw 0x0, time 31281532, (165,-10), root:(265,118),
    state 0x2000, keycode 40 (keysym 0x6d7, Cyrillic_ve), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d0 b2) "в"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x169, subw 0x0, time 31281636, (165,-10), root:(265,118),
    state 0x2000, keycode 40 (keysym 0x6d7, Cyrillic_ve), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d0 b2) "в"
    XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d0 b2) "в"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x169, subw 0x0, time 31281688, (165,-10), root:(265,118),
    state 0x2000, keycode 39 (keysym 0x6d9, Cyrillic_yeru), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d1 8b) "ы"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x169, subw 0x0, time 31281781, (165,-10), root:(265,118),
    state 0x2000, keycode 40 (keysym 0x6d7, Cyrillic_ve), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d0 b2) "в"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Но это только тесты. Захватывать клавиши для прослушки придется как-то иначе.

Comment: Насколько я понял, спрашивающему несколько другое нужно было...

Comment: это он разъяснил после того как я ответил...
пусть сформулирует свой вопрос получше. и кейлогер на баше не так просто написать.)